# Replace strings in files by Python, recursively in given directory and its subdirectories?

Tags: python, regex, search, replace, operating-system

How can you replace a string match inside a file with the given replacement, recursively, inside a given directory and its subdirectories?

Pseudo-code:

```
import os
import re
from os.path import walk
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/noa/Desktop/codes"):
        for name in dirs:
                re.search("dbname=noa user=noa", "dbname=masi user=masi")
                   // I am trying to replace here a given match in a file
```

Comment: Hammers for nails, screws for screwdrivers. If you really need an extra emphasis on efficiency, Perl is the perfect tool for this job. Not saying "don't use Python," but consider your requirements.

Comment: Chris: I know Perl, but I want to know Python too.

Comment: @Chris - Perl?  How about `find` and `xargs`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Put all this code into a file called `mass_replace`.  Under Linux or Mac OS X, you can do `chmod +x mass_replace` and then just run this.  Under Windows, you can run it with `python mass_replace` followed by the appropriate arguments.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import re
import sys

# list of extensions to replace
DEFAULT_REPLACE_EXTENSIONS = None
# example: uncomment next line to only replace *.c, *.h, and/or *.txt
# DEFAULT_REPLACE_EXTENSIONS = (".c", ".h", ".txt")

def try_to_replace(fname, replace_extensions=DEFAULT_REPLACE_EXTENSIONS):
    if replace_extensions:
        return fname.lower().endswith(replace_extensions)
    return True


def file_replace(fname, pat, s_after):
    # first, see if the pattern is even in the file.
    with open(fname) as f:
        if not any(re.search(pat, line) for line in f):
            return # pattern does not occur in file so we are done.

    # pattern is in the file, so perform replace operation.
    with open(fname) as f:
        out_fname = fname + ".tmp"
        out = open(out_fname, "w")
        for line in f:
            out.write(re.sub(pat, s_after, line))
        out.close()
        os.rename(out_fname, fname)


def mass_replace(dir_name, s_before, s_after, replace_extensions=DEFAULT_REPLACE_EXTENSIONS):
    pat = re.compile(s_before)
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir_name):
        for fname in filenames:
            if try_to_replace(fname, replace_extensions):
                fullname = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
                file_replace(fullname, pat, s_after)

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    u = "Usage: mass_replace <dir_name> <string_before> <string_after>\n"
    sys.stderr.write(u)
    sys.exit(1)

mass_replace(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
```

EDIT: I have changed the above code from the original answer.  There are several changes.  First, `mass_replace()` now calls `re.compile()` to pre-compile the search pattern; second, to check what extension the file has, we now pass in a tuple of file extensions to `.endswith()` rather than calling `.endswith()` three times; third, it now uses the `with` statement available in recent versions of Python; and finally, `file_replace()` now checks to see if the pattern is found within the file, and doesn't rewrite the file if the pattern is not found.  (The old version would rewrite every file, changing the timestamps even if the output file was identical to the input file; this was inelegant.)

EDIT: I changed this to default to replacing every file, but with one line you can edit to limit it to particular extensions.  I think replacing every file is a more useful out-of-the-box default.  This could be extended with a list of extensions or filenames not to touch, options to make it case insensitive, etc.

EDIT: In a comment, @asciimo pointed out a bug.  I edited this to fix the bug.  `str.endswith()` is documented to accept a tuple of strings to try, but not a list.  Fixed.  Also, I made a couple of the functions accept an optional argument to let you pass in a tuple of extensions; it should be pretty easy to modify this to accept a command-line argument to specify which extensions.

Comment: I like the logic of your code in separating the logical parts to functions.

Comment: In `file_replace` I had to change `os.rename` to `shutil.move` for it to work for me in Windows.

Comment: On my system (python 2.7.5), I got `TypeError: endswith first arg must be str, unicode, or tuple, not list`.  Changing the list to a tuple worked e.g. `[".fudge", "pancake"]` -> `(".fudge", "pancake")`.

Comment: @asciimo, thank you for pointing that out.  Usually I'm good about testing code before posting it here, but I guess I was sloppy when I wrote that!  Fixed now.

Comment: Two fixes for Windows: 1) Unindent `os.rename(out_fname, fname)` so that it is outside the `with` scope. 2) Precede this line with `os.remove(fname)` so that `rename()` succeeds.

Answer (score 9):

Do you really need regular expressions?

```
import os

def recursive_replace( root, pattern, replace )
    for dir, subdirs, names in os.walk( root ):
        for name in names:
            path = os.path.join( dir, name )
            text = open( path ).read()
            if pattern in text:
                open( path, 'w' ).write( text.replace( pattern, replace ) )
```

Comment: Globbing seems to be betters than regex in this case.

Comment: Does 'root' here really mean the lowest level of the directory hierarchy? Or is it only a variable where you can store the Path to be searched?

Comment: @Masi:  "root" is just a parameter name, the lowest level directory to start searching from.  you can name it anything you like

Answer (score 4):

Of course, if you just want to get it done without coding it up, use find and xargs:

```
find /home/noa/Desktop/codes -type f -print0 | \
xargs -0 sed --in-place "s/dbname=noa user=noa/dbname=masi user=masi"
```

(And you could likely do this with find's -exec or something as well, but I prefer xargs.)

Comment: The find and sed solution is fine when you have a simple task, such as "replace the string in every *.txt file".  Once you have a more complicated set of files to match, and if you have multiple replacements to do, the Python solution really wins.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would find and replace strings in files using python. This is a simple little function that will recursively search a directories for a string and replace it with a string. You can also limit files with a certain file extension like the example below.

```
import os, fnmatch
def findReplace(directory, find, replace, filePattern):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(directory)):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, filePattern):
            filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            with open(filepath) as f:
                s = f.read()
            s = s.replace(find, replace)
            with open(filepath, "w") as f:
                f.write(s)
```

This allows you to do something like:

```
findReplace("some_dir", "find this", "replace with this", "*.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

```
import re, os
import fnmatch
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(directory)):
       for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, filePattern):
           filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
           with open("namelist.wps", 'a') as out:
               with open("namelist.wps", 'r') as readf:
                   for line in readf:
                       line = re.sub(r"dbname=noa user=noa", "dbname=masi user=masi", line)
                       out.write(line)
```

Comment: I forgot the:import fnmatch

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You can edit your answer by clicking `edit` at the bottom of the body of your question. Please, see if the edit is correct. I like your `with open("namelist.wps", 'r') as readf` which is much more clearer than breaking the thing to two lines. The last for -loop is also clear. Very good additions!