# Bulk replacing function name with another in C

Tags: python, c, shell, text, awk

How can I replace a C function name with another using standard tools/scripts like: `shell`/`awk`/`grep`/`python` etc?

For example I need to blindly replace the `assert(a>b)` statement with `MyAssert(a>b)` in the entire codebase. Only function name needs to be replaced.

Comment: How careful do you want it to be?  `printf("No assert() here\n");`?  `/* assert that the world is good! */`?

Comment: It is okay to replace "No assert() here\n". But not okay to replace a non function text like "assert that the world is good!" . I need function name replacement, without touching non function text with same name.

Comment: OK; that's reasonably sane.  And presumably you want to handle `assert (space < open_parenthesis)` with one or more spaces between the function name and the open parenthesis but don't care about `assert /* Nonsense */ (paranoia != insanity);` because no-one in their right mind writes code with comments between the function name and the open parenthesis.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Isn't `assert` a macro? So interposing a comment would prevent its invocation.

Comment: @luserdroog: Comments are removed by the time macros are evaluated, so comments between macro name and its opening parenthesis don't affect the invocation of the macro.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed`

```
sed -r 's/\bassert\(a>b\)\b/MyAssert(a>b)/' file
```

- `\b` looks for word boundary so that it looks for an exact match.
- This will print the file to STDOUT which you can either redirect to another file or use `-i` option to make changes in-place in your existing file.

Comment: I think you could simplify the code by not matching the `a>b` or the close parenthesis – that was an example.  But this is good if your `sed` supports extended regular expressions with `\b`; at least, it ensures that only the word `assert` on its own gets translated, not words such as `test_assertion()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -iname "*.c" -exec sed -i.bak "s/assert/MyAssert/g" {} \;
```

This will apply the change to every .c file in place under the current directory, and create a .c.bak file containing the original.  If you want to get rid of those, you could remove them with this:

```
find . -iname "*.bak" -exec rm {} \;
```

Of course, make sure you have a copy of everything first, I might have messed up :-)

If you want to catch cases more carefully, avoiding 'assert' in the middle of another word, but getting it at the beginning of a line, but it starts to get ugly, and still isn't perfect:

```
find . -iname "*.c" -exec sed -i.bak -e "s/\([^a-zA-Z0-9S]\)assert(/\1MyAssert(/g" -e "s/^assert(/MyAssert(/" {} \;
```

Comment: I see problems with `test_assertion()` becoming `test_MyAssertion()`.

Comment: To fix that the regex needs to be more complicated, for example, changing it to "s/assert(/MyAssert(/g", which would catch 'assert(', so would not affect test_assertion.  Ideally you'd want to check the character before the a, but then it starts to get complicated.  If adding the '(' works for you, that's the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Python script to solve this problem.  Good things about it:

- It doesn't modify any files that do not contain the string.  Timestamps won't change unless the file actually was modified.
- You can tweak it to only look in filenames matching a pattern (like `*.c` or whatever).

[Replace strings in files by Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597649/replace-strings-in-files-by-python/1597755#1597755)